# declare value of property as equal to that of parent

Tags: php, oop

I have a parent class called 'person'. 'individual' is a child class of 'person'.

In 'person', I have a protected property called '$_pk_person';

In 'individual', I want to create a protected property called '$_fk_individual_person' whose value is equal to the inherited value of '$_pk_person'.

Shouldn't I be able to do this by merely stating:

```
protected $_fk_individual_person = {$this->_pk_person};
```

or

```
protected $_fk_individual_person = $_pk_person;
```

or

```
protected $_fk_individual_person = get_pk_person();
```

or

```
protected $_fk_individual_person = self::get_pk_person();
```

or

```
protected $_fk_individual_person = self::_pk_person;
```

or

```
protected $_fk_individual_person = parent::_pk_person;
```

or

```
protected $_fk_individual_person = parent::get_pk_person();
```

in class 'individual'??

None of them are working. I must be committing a fundamental error somewhere, as I am a complete novice.

Please help me out.

AFTER USING CONSTRUCTOR, my class looked like this:

```
class individual extends person {
public $_fk_individual_person;
function __construct() {
    $this->_fk_individual_person = $this->_pk_person;
}
}
```

And I tested it, but screen was blank:
    $xyz = new individual();

```
$xyz->pk_person='abcd';

echo $xyz->_fk_individual_person;
```

Where did I goof up now? I'm sorry, but I'm an absolute novice (started oop coding just yesterday, this being my first class)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot do this without a constructor. Because the initialization must be const or known at compile time. Look an manual:

> Class member variables are called "properties". You may also see them
>   referred to using other terms such as "attributes" or "fields", but
>   for the purposes of this reference we will use "properties". They are
>   defined by using one of the keywords public, protected, or private,
>   followed by a normal variable declaration. **This declaration may
>   include an initialization, but this initialization must be a constant
>   value--that is, it must be able to be evaluated at compile time and
>   must not depend on run-time information in order to be evaluated.**

But using constuctor is the way to go:

```
class individual extends person {
    protected $_fk_individual_person;
    function __construct() {
        $this->_fk_individual_person = $this->_pk_person;
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesnt seem to work. This is what I did: class individual extends person {
    public $_fk_individual_person;
    function __construct() {
        $this->_fk_individual_person = $this->_pk_person;
    }
}

$xyz = new individual();

$xyz->pk_person='abcd';

echo $xyz->_fk_individual_person;

Comment: @Chinmay If you assign the value *after* the constructor has run, that obviously won't work. Not to mention that you cannot assign to a `protected` property from outside.

Comment: Oh.. My bad.. Thanks a lot. But is there a way, just out of curiosity, for 2 variables to be equal to each other. I mean, you change one, the other automatically changes. As such, both occupy just one location in the servers memory. -Thanks

Comment: sure you can, using references ;) in constructor you should write `$this->_fk_individual_person = &$this->_pk_person;` instead of `$this->_fk_individual_person = $this->_pk_person;`

Answer (score 2):

You need to perform the assignment in the child class constructor.

```
class B extends A{
   function __construct() {
      $this->_fk_individual_person = $this->_pk_person;
   }
}
```